# Do i need visa to europe with usa reffugge travel doc

Tags: visas

Do i need visa to travel to the united kingdom with USA refugee travel documents ?

Comment: Your questions title and body are asking two different questions, can you clarify which you actually want answers on?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica that is not correct.  A citizen of a country can only benefit from a visa exemption for citizens of that country by traveling with that country's passport, which is something refugees generally should not do.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica isn't "whether you need a UK visa" saying something about visa exemption?  Consider the case of a Canadian citizen who is a refugee in the US.  The UK will not grant the visa exemption on the basis of a US refugee travel document that states Canadian citizenship.  So, for a refugee who travels with a refugee travel document, citizenship is not relevant to whether the traveler needs a UK visa.  (In fact, to use the tool you link to, a refugee should choose "stateless or refugee," regardless of what the document says about citizenship.)

Comment: @phoog While I didn't address visa exemption, my comment does suggest it might apply. I'll delete my comment. If completing the uk.gov tool, "Stateless or Refugee" would be the correct choice for the OP.